# MS Access report - Data randomly cut when exporting

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have MS Access report which when viewed in MS Access shows all of the data correctly. However when exporting to a Text / HTML file. It cuts around 30 characters (variable) from one of the fields being displayed.

There appears to be no pattern to which groups / records are altered by this, and the number of characters varies between them, though usually around 30 characters cut. However the data is always cut in the same field.

I have had a look around and not really found anything specific to this. Is anyone aware of a possible cause and solution to this?

Kind regards,
I am using MS Access 2010

The Field in Design view shows;

```
    =[Band] & " - " & [Body] & " <br> Max Reported 1g SAR = " & Max([Maximumvalue] & "(W/kg)")
```

The Field in Form view shows;

```
    DCS 1800 - Body-worn <br> Max Reported 1g SAR = X(W/kg)
```

The field in the exported file shows;

```
    Reported 1g SAR = X(W/kg)
```

Comment: How do you do the export?

Comment: Command button prompted VBA. The process exports the report to a HTML file, Opens the HTML file with MS Word, and then saves it as a RTF File. 
@Andre - Thanks for the reply.
I have checked the output of the file in HTML format and the error is present here.
I have also exported to a text file using the access export function on the ribbon, the error is also present here.

Comment: Sorry, I meant which VBA method do you use? And do you export from Report view or Print Preview? -- Since it also happens when exporting via ribbon, can you post a screenshot of the report (or the part that shows the field)?

Comment: @Andre
Here is the code for the export in VBA

        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rpt_results", _
 acFormatTXT, pathreport, False

Comment: @Andre

I have tried exporting from both Report and Print.

It also appears to be working now... I "cut" the field, exported to see the outcome to see if it was specific to this field, or an issue elsewhere just impacting this field. When it worked correctly I "pasted" the exact field back in and it is working again fine.

I'm not really sure I can say what the cause / solution was though.